# How to batch resize many photos - but keep timestamp intact?

Tags: linux, batch, photos, image-editing

I have thousands of photos in many folders. I want to batch resize them to e.g. 3000px on the longest dimension *and keep the timestamp intact.*

I have used the wonderfully simple tool [Phatch](http://photobatch.wikidot.com/) to resize all files but the files' original timestamps are gone and there's no setting in Phatch to avoid this. 
So I now have a master folder with all the originals, and another folder with the Phatch results - just in case this helps.

- Platform: Linux (Ubuntu)
- Source files: 2000 JPG files in many subfolders
- Target: resized to 3000px (unless already smaller than that),

  - either resize files in place
  - or save as copy using same folder structure
  - keep original file names and timestamps intact

I'm not enough of a Linux person (yet) to know what tools I could use (imagemagick? mogrify?) and how but I'll happily accept any hints!

Comment: `touch` supports timestamps.  You still have the old files, thus you have the old filename with assorted date. It is possible to write a script using this information and touch.  (But ENOTENOUGHCOFFEE so I am not writing it atm).

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like an evening's worth of coding to my unskilled hands. Welp, that's how I learn!

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this, using convert from package **imagemagick**, putting new files in /tmp/new or a similar directory:

```
mkdir /tmp/new
find . -iname '*.jpg' |
while read file
do convert -resize '>3000x>3000' "$file" /tmp/new/"$file"
   touch -r "$file" /tmp/new/"$file"
done
```

If happy with the result, move them with:

```
rsync -a /tmp/new/ .
rm -fr /tmp/new
```

Comment: +1 for the while read file .... touch -r "$file" /tmp/new/"$file" part.  That should work even with another program then convert. (or with already converted files).

Answer (score 2):

Actually `mogrify` from the same package with `-define preserve-timestamp=true` do the same, but be carefull, **this will overwrite original image**.